# Selenium WebDriver - Datadriven testing

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, data-driven-tests

I am testing a website using Selenium Webdriver.

Eclipse has to fetch username from excel.

When the Username data in excel is `xyz`
my test enters the username value twice, `xyzxyz`, into the form.

How can I fix it so that the data is entered only once.

Code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("xyz");
```

Comment: Try clearing the field first using ` driver.findElement(By.id("username")). clear();` . Then try the above code. I am assuming the data in **sendKeys** above is fetched from the excel sheet using relevant method.

Comment: "Eclipse has to fetch username from excel" -- really?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following statement before the `SendKeys` line, so that the field is cleared before the filename is entered.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")). clear();
```

(Answer derived from a comment by @Subh.)